# Net income graphed as a function of pre-tax gross income?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

Background: both as a self-employed, and with a single-person company, the relationship between amount of money made, and post-tax net income seems non-trivial. Self-employed professionals have several tax brackets, and class4 NIC. In eg. a company paying out dividends there's corporation tax, and personal allowance brackets on dividends.

Has anyone attempted to capture the multiple inflation points in this relationship via a simple graph, e.g. showing gross income on X axis, and net revenue on Y-axis? (Instant accept for linked solutions).

Comment: I imagine this would be fairly complicated to plot in a functional form because the tax laws change from year to year.

Comment: Fortunately, at least within one tax year, this graph is constant -so plotting it for eg. 2013 would be awesome!

Comment: Wouldn't the graph be different based on how you earned that gross income? I'm only loosely familiar with US tax law, but the tax paid (and therefore net revenue) would be different if you earned 100K from capital gains, labor income, etc. That means that you won't have a simple functional form of `revenue = F(gross income)`.

Comment: John -exactly! This is why capturing each financial instrument separately would allow shopping around for appropiate structure based on income levels anticipated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2014/15 it looks something like this:

[image: Net income]

To make it a bit clearer, let's also plot the difference in net income for self-employment and a single person company compared to employment:

[image: Net saving compared to employment]

Self-employment is slightly worse between £5885 and about £10,500 because Class 2 NI kicks in before the employed person starts paying any tax. After that, self-employment is better because you pay 9% Class 4 NI rather than 12% Class 1 NI. Once higher rate tax kicks in, the saving stops growing.

The single-person company is most tax-efficient at all points, ignoring any accountancy costs it incurs. Strange things happen between £100k and about £135k because the withdrawal of the personal allowance kicks in at a different point when receiving dividends.

We can also plot the percentage of income paid as tax for each case:

[image: Effective tax rates]

The strange kink for self-employment below £10k is caused by Class 2 NI again. Employment and self-employment both gradually tend towards paying 47%, reaching 46.5% for £2m gross income. The company tends towards 44.44%, reaching 43.6% for £2m gross income.

Comment: This is really useful, would especially love to see one for 2016-2017 :)

Answer (score -1):

You first compute your Ordinary Income (which includes Dividends, since they are taxed as OI), then you apply the standard tax bracket function to it, which is a piecewise linear function f() such that TAX = f(INCOME). It can be found at [About.com](http://taxes.about.com/od/Federal-Income-Taxes/qt/Tax-Rates-For-The-2013-Tax-Year.htm). You can transform this into NET_INCOME = g(INCOME) = INCOME - TAX = INCOME - f(INCOME). Presumably g() is what you want to graph. I've actually graphed it before:

[image]

Not too interesting, even on a LogLog scale. More interesting is the marginal tax rate, which is the derivative of f(), or the negative of the derivative of g():

[image]

ST (straight tax) shows what the marginal tax rate would look like if f() was just f(x)=k*x or f(x)=k*x+c, i.e. a straight/flat tax.

The net tax rate (f(x)/x) actually gets more interesting if you also include [federal subsidies/deductions](Src: http://fbheron.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/fedassistance_ft.jpg) as a negative tax:

[image]

Capital Gains are taxed separately and have (almost) nothing to do with this function. Corporate tax is not payed by you (although the burden of the tax [technical term] may fall upon you).

Sorry I couldn't simplify; taxes are just complicated.

Comment: On the last graph I mixed single-filing-status taxes with family-filing-status subsidies, so it's not perfect. Still, check it out, anyone making under $50k is receiving more than they pay into the system!

Comment: -1: The question is tagged for the UK, but your graph is for US federal taxes.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the tag, only the question. Thanks for pointing that out.